# AppleScript debug with shellcheck

Tags: applescript, shellcheck

I am a complete novice using Script Editor. I don't even know what language this is written in, but I'm trying to use shellcheck.net to debug this:

```
var=value LDMIcon to path to resource "LDM_Icon.icns" in bundle (path to me)
set CurrentOS to do shell script "sw_vers -productVersion | cut -c 1-4"
```

shellcheck says this;

```
var=value LDMIcon to path to resource "LDM_Icon.icns" in bundle (path to me)
>>                                                              ^-- SC1036 (error): '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
>>                                                              ^-- SC1088 (error): Parsing stopped here. Invalid use of parentheses?
```

I've tried to fix it using the github tips (SC1036 etc) with no luck. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: It might help to explain exactly what it is you are trying to do - you can’t debug AppleScript by using a utility for analyzing shell scripts.

Comment: I'm trying to make a bootable USB of macOS Mountain Lion 10.8 to reset an old Macbook, using DiskMaker X. When I try to open DiskMaker X I get this message
**
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `echo /Users/jimmy-nz/Dropbox/My Mac (Matthew’s iMac)/Downloads/Install OS X Mountain Lion.app | wc -l ' **